# Manipualtors in c++?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char c[100],a[100];
    cout.precision(2);
    cout<<5.169<<endl;
}
```

I get output as 5.2, but theoretically output should be 5.17, can anybody please explain me this ?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/precision/  read this at first. Here is the solution of your misunderstanding.    Using the default floating-point notation, the precision field specifies the maximum number of meaningful digits to display in total counting both those before and those after the decimal point. Notice that it is not a minimum, and therefore it does not pad the displayed number with trailing zeros if the number can be displayed with less digits than the precision.

Answer (score 0):

```
get (1) 
streamsize precision() const;
set (2) 
streamsize precision (streamsize prec);
```

Get/Set floating-point decimal precision
The first form (1) returns the value of the current floating-point precision field for the stream.
The second form (2) also sets it to a new value.

The floating-point precision determines the maximum number of digits to be written on insertion operations to express floating-point values. How this is interpreted depends on whether the floatfield format flag is set to a specific notation (either fixed or scientific) or it is unset (using the default notation, which is not necessarily equivalent to either fixed nor scientific).

For the default locale:
Using the default floating-point notation, the precision field specifies the **maximum number of meaningful digits to display in total counting both those before and those after the decimal point.** Notice that it is not a minimum, and therefore it does not pad the displayed number with trailing zeros if the number can be displayed with less digits than the precision.
In both the fixed and scientific notations, the precision field specifies exactly how many digits to display after the decimal point, even if this includes trailing decimal zeros. The digits before the decimal point are not relevant for the precision in this case.